# RuntimeException: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am getting a runtimeException with the following code, does anyone know why?

```
public class FragsApplicationActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

SuggestionFrags class

```
public class SuggestionFrags extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.samplefragsapplication.SuggestionFrags" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting this exception:

```
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samplefragsapplication/com.samplefragsapplication.FragsApplicationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.samplefragsapplication.FragsApplicationActivity.onCreate(FragsApplicationActivity.java:12)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.samplefragsapplication-2.apk]
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:544)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
11-23 18:09:23.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2436):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
```

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace from LogCat instead of just one line?

Answer (score 13):

If you are going to use `Fragments` you need to extend `FragmentActivity` not `Activity`.

Comment: this is valid only when compatibility library is used.

Answer (score 6):

To fix this issue you have to extends from FragmentActivity instead of Activity in the FragsApplicationActivity.

Answer (score 4):

The proper form will be

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.samplefragsapplication.SuggestionFrags" />
```

UPD: judging by the logcat output, you don't have fragments available. If you're running a pre-Honeycomb android (but >= 1.6), you can use the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). Fragments were introduced in 3.0.

Comment: I am using compatibility library.  I set my minSdkVersion="7".  But that still doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The exception `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: #... Error inflating class fragment` might happen if you manipulate with `getActivity()` inside your fragment before `onActivityCreated()` get called. In such case you receive a wrong activity reference and can't rely on that.

For instance the next pattern is wrong:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout..., container, false);

    Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id...);
    button.setOnClickListener(...); - another problem: button is null

    return view;
}
```

Comment: how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue, and what I found was that in my main.xml I was incorrectly referencing the fragment class.

Instead of:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag_capt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.company.test.applicationname.fragmentname" />
```

try:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/frag_capt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.company.test.DetailFrag" />
```

This fixed the issue for me.
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment1"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure android:name="className" is the first parameter in the list

ex

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.name.first"
    android:id="@+id/"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to summarise:

- Extend from FragmentActivity
- Follow this structure in your layout

  ```
  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  />
  ```